# Spring Data @Query on fields

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

The @Query on the property retrieves the values only if I retrieve the entity from the DB.

```
@NodeEntity
public class Team
{
    @GraphId
    private Long nodeId;

    @RelatedTo (type = "PREVIOUSLY_KNOWN_AS")
    private Team previouslyKnownAs;

    @Query ("START t=node({self}) MATCH t-[:PREVIOUSLY_KNOWN_AS]-other RETURN other")
        private Iterable<Team> aliases;
}
```

The below test works only if I uncomment the line to read it explicitly from the db. Why is it necessary? I see the query being run after the `save(t)` but the `alias` field is `null` if I doesn't read it from DB by uncommenting the line

```
@Test
public void alias()
{
    Team t = new Team();
    t.setName("Alpharetta One");

    Team prev = new Team();
    prev.setName("Previous Name");
    teamRepo.save(prev);

    t.setPreviouslyKnownAs(prev);
    teamRepo.save(t);

    //t = teamRepo.findOne(t.getNodeId());//only works if I uncomment
    assertNotNull(t.getAliases());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 t=teamRepo.save(t);
```

I dont think that the save operation will update the POJO which you give to it, while the returned Object should be a managed enttiy. 
The key lies in the reference documentation

> The @Query annotation leverages the delegation infrastructure supported by Spring Data Neo4j.It provides **dynamic fields** which, when accessed, return the values selected by the provided query language expression.

Since it is a dynamic field, the value isnt instanciated but instead fetched from the DB every time the get method is called. To do this, a proxy object has to be used. However there is no way for SDN to change your t Object reference to the proxy object, and thats why its not working, if you are not using the entity returned by save().